# How to create a bulk data endpoint in woocommerce without breaking the site performance

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am trying to create a wordpress plugin that exports or sends out (through an API) bulk data resource by resource (such as products, orders, customers, etc) of a woocommerce site without affecting the performance of the site.

But I am new to php and finding it difficult.

Also, I was planning to use WP-Cron to build the bulk data on certain time interval in order to avoid the hit in performance. But, from some research, I got to know that WP-Cron is not a reliable solution to my goal as it is [not a regular cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) and also, it can be [disabled easily](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048323291-Disabling-WP-CRON-to-Improve-Overall-Site-Performance).

As my idea requires a regular bulk data building approach, I am now looking out for different options such as recursive calling.

I have exposed an endpoint where I will be receiving some required details and will call the class that will take care of the bulk data building.

```
public function getCCBulkSync( $request )
    {
        $entity = $_GET['entity'];
        $startDate = $_GET['start_date'];
        $endDate = $_GET['end_date'];
        $delivery_url = $_GET['delivery_url'];
        $limit = $_GET['limit'];
        if(!$delivery_url) return 'Delivery Url cannot be null';
        include 'class-wc-cc-bulk-data-builder.php';
        $bulkBuilder = WC_CC_Bulk_Data_Builder::getInstance();
        $bulkBuilder = ($bulkBuilder === NULL || $bulkBuilder->getObjectDetails()['entity'] === NULL) ? $bulkBuilder->setObjectDetails($entity, $delivery_url, $startDate, $endDate, $limit) : $bulkBuilder;
        return 'Bulk sync initiated! Check later for the completion!!!';
    }
```

The bulk data builder class code is given below

```
class WC_Bulk_Data_Builder 
{
    private static $instance = NULL;
    protected $entity = NULL;
    protected $startDate = NULL;
    protected $endDate = NULL;
    protected $delivery_url = NULL;
    protected $dataCount = 0;
    protected $limit = 0;

    static public function getInstance()
    {
       if (self::$instance === NULL)
          self::$instance = new WC_Bulk_Data_Builder();
       return self::$instance;
    }

    protected function __construct($entity = NULL, $delivery_url = NULL, $startDate = NULL, $endDate = NULL, $limit = 1000)
    {
        $this->entity = $entity;
        $this->delivery_url = $delivery_url;
        $this->startDate = $startDate;
        $this->endDate = $endDate;
        $this->limit = $limit;
    }

    public function getObjectDetails() {
        $objData = array();
        $objData['entity'] = $this->entity;
        $objData['startDate'] = $this->startDate;
        $objData['endDate'] = $this->endDate;
        $objData['deliveryUrl'] = $this->delivery_url;
        $objData['dataCount'] = $this->dataCount;
        $objData['limit'] = $this->limit;
        return $objData;
    }

    public function setObjectDetails($entity = NULL, $delivery_url = NULL, $startDate = NULL, $endDate = NULL, $limit = 1000) {
        $this->entity = $entity;
        $this->delivery_url = $delivery_url;
        $this->startDate = $startDate;
        $this->endDate = $endDate;
        $this->limit = $limit;
        $this->bulk_data_builder();
        return self::$instance;
    }    

    function bulk_data_builder()
    {
        $entity = $this->entity;
        if($entity === 'order') {
            $this->build_order_data();
        }
        sleep(20);
        $this->bulk_data_builder();
    }

    protected function build_order_data()
    {
        $ordersArray = wc_get_orders( array(
            'limit' => 250,
            'offset' => $this->dataCount,
            'orderby' => 'ID',
            'order' => 'ASC',
        ) );
        $this->dataCount += count($ordersArray);
        $orders = array();
        foreach($ordersArray as $order_index=>$order) {
            $orders[$order_index]=$order->get_data();
            $orders[$order_index]['refunds'] = $order->get_refunds();
        }
        
        $header_args = array_keys($orders[0]);
        $output = fopen( 'order_csv_export.csv', 'a+' );
        fputcsv($output, $header_args);
        foreach($orders AS $order_item){
            foreach($header_args AS $ind=>$key) {
                if('array' === gettype($order_item[$key])) $order_item[$key] = json_encode($order_item[$key]);
            }
            fputcsv($output, $order_item);
        }
        if($dataCount>=$limit)
        {
            $dataCount = 0;
            $req_headers = array();
            $req_headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8';
            $req_headers[] = 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=order_csv_export.csv';
            $cURL = curl_init();
            $setopt_array = array(CURLOPT_URL => $delivery_url,    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $req_headers); 
            curl_setopt_array($cURL, $setopt_array);
            $json_response_data = curl_exec($cURL);
            curl_close($cURL);
            exit;
        }
        fclose($output);
    }
}
```

Now, what I am expecting is the recursive calling on same `bulk_data_builder()` method which should build the data continuously on a 20 seconds interval or any other way to do the same until the record count reaches the limit, so that I can send the bulk data built, to the delivery_url.

But, the mentioned method is not getting called recursively. Only for the first time the method is called and giving back 250 records.

As I am new to php, I am not sure about the async functionality also.

Can someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong or what I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure your endpoint causes performance problems?  Your simple use of `wc_get_orders()` probably does not cause contention problems on your MariaDB / MySQL server. So, even if delivering data to the endpoint requester takes a while, other users of your system should still be able to function normally. You may have to  use [set_time_limit()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to prevent your endpoint from timing out. And, php knows nothing of tail recursion, so even if you get your recursive approach to work, you'll eventually cause a, well, stack overflow.

Comment: If you aren't using the Query Monitor plugin, start using it for this kind of development.

Comment: @O.Jones, until now, I am not having any trouble with the performance. But, the recursive calling to the data builder method is not at all working.
Also, I am not sure whether I can use other plugins, as the primary work of the plugin that I am trying is this data building and it will have some other tasks.
So I can't stop working on this plugin as well.
Is there any other approach where I can achieve this bulk data building without using any other plugin?